# How to disable field based on condition on form load in uipath forms?

Tags: javascript, uipath, formio, uipath-activity

I came across a problem where if a field has value already present, it needs to be disabled.

I tried to use Logic with simple JavaScript trigger but I’m not sure when this trigger is evaluated, but the trigger is executed onchange or onblur.

Trigger:
[image]

Action:
[image]

This works but since trigger executes onblur or onchange, as soon as I type some characters the field is disabled.

It should execute only once on form load. I have tried adding a hidden HTML component but calling the onload function is not working.

HTML component code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="myFunction();">
<script>
function myFunction() {
if(document.getElementById('empName').innerHTML.length > 0)
  {
    document.getElementById('empName').setAttribute('disabled ', 'disabled');
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm not very good with JavaScript or have used form.io before.
Also, I could not understand how to use Trigger type Event and call it externally.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the dependent field by:

1. Setting the logic trigger to be of 'Simple' type and check the parent field to have '' (blank) value.
2. Have the logic action setup as you have already done

[image]